# Creating a Databricks Job with Separate Tasks and Parameters from within a notebook

Tags: python, databricks, jobs

I'm trying to create a Databricks job using the Databricks Python SDK, and I want to set up separate tasks within the job that call a Python file with specific parameters. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
import os
import time
import json

from databricks.sdk import WorkspaceClient
from databricks.sdk.service import jobs

# Initialize the Databricks Workspace client
w = WorkspaceClient()

# Define the path to my Databricks notebook
script_path = f'jobs/sync_clients.py'

# Define job parameters
config1 = {}  # pydantic
config2 = {}  # pydantic
some_string = "/path/to/something"  
client = {}  

job_params = {
    "config1": config1.model_dump(),
    "config2": config2.model_dump(),
    "some_string": some_string,
    "client": client
}

# Create the job with separate tasks
created_job = w.jobs.create(name=f'client-{time.time_ns()}',
                            tasks=[
                                jobs.Task(description=f"{client.ID}",
                                          existing_cluster_id=dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().tags().get("clusterId"), 
                                          spark_python_task=jobs.SparkPythonTask(python_file=script_path, parameters=job_params),
                                          task_key=client.ID,
                                          timeout_seconds=0,
                                          )
                            ])

# Run the job
run_by_id = w.jobs.run_now(job_id=created_job.job_id).result()

# Delete the job (optional)
w.jobs.delete(job_id=created_job.job_id)
```

but I am getting this error when trying to create it:

`TypeError: Object of type JavaObject is not JSON serializable`

Ideally I would serialize the job parameters as a string with `json.dumps()`
and load it on the job with `json.loads()`

in addition to that
Ultimately this will use a new cluster or another cluster, but it is not created yet, so I'm trying to run it on the same cluster

I'm quite new to databricks and feeling lost in the documentation for that sdk

full error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command-22633648340896>:18
     10 notebook_path = f'jobs/sync_clients_metadata_tables.py'
     12 job_params = {
     13     "config1": config1.model_dump(),
     14     "config2": config2.model_dump(),
     15     "some_string": some_string,
     16     "client": first_client
     17 }
---> 18 created_job = w.jobs.create(name=f'client-metadata-ingestion-{time.time_ns()}',
     19                             tasks=[
     20                                 jobs.Task(description=f"{first_client.ID}",
     21                                           existing_cluster_id= dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().tags().get("clusterId"),
     22                                           spark_python_task=jobs.SparkPythonTask(python_file=notebook_path,parameters=job_params),
     23                                           task_key=first_client.ID,
     24                                           timeout_seconds=0,
     25                                           )
     26                             ])
     28 run_by_id = w.jobs.run_now(job_id=created_job.job_id).result()
     30 w.jobs.delete(job_id=created_job.job_id)

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/databricks/sdk/service/jobs.py:2902, in JobsAPI.create(self, access_control_list, compute, continuous, email_notifications, format, git_source, health, job_clusters, max_concurrent_runs, name, notification_settings, parameters, run_as, schedule, tags, tasks, timeout_seconds, trigger, webhook_notifications)
   2900 if webhook_notifications is not None: body['webhook_notifications'] = webhook_notifications.as_dict()
   2901 headers = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', }
-> 2902 res = self._api.do('POST', '/api/2.1/jobs/create', body=body, headers=headers)
   2903 return CreateResponse.from_dict(res)

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/databricks/sdk/core.py:997, in ApiClient.do(self, method, path, query, headers, body, raw, files, data)
    995     headers = {}
    996 headers['User-Agent'] = self._user_agent_base
--> 997 response = self._session.request(method,
    998                                  f"{self._cfg.host}{path}",
    999                                  params=self._fix_query_string(query),
   1000                                  json=body,
   1001                                  headers=headers,
   1002                                  files=files,
   1003                                  data=data,
   1004                                  stream=raw)
   1005 try:
   1006     self._record_request_log(response, raw=raw or data is not None or files is not None)

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py:575, in Session.request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    562 # Create the Request.
    563 req = Request(
    564     method=method.upper(),
    565     url=url,
   (...)
    573     hooks=hooks,
    574 )
--> 575 prep = self.prepare_request(req)
    577 proxies = proxies or {}
    579 settings = self.merge_environment_settings(
    580     prep.url, proxies, stream, verify, cert
    581 )

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py:486, in Session.prepare_request(self, request)
    483     auth = get_netrc_auth(request.url)
    485 p = PreparedRequest()
--> 486 p.prepare(
    487     method=request.method.upper(),
    488     url=request.url,
    489     files=request.files,
    490     data=request.data,
    491     json=request.json,
    492     headers=merge_setting(
    493         request.headers, self.headers, dict_class=CaseInsensitiveDict
    494     ),
    495     params=merge_setting(request.params, self.params),
    496     auth=merge_setting(auth, self.auth),
    497     cookies=merged_cookies,
    498     hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
    499 )
    500 return p

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py:371, in PreparedRequest.prepare(self, method, url, headers, files, data, params, auth, cookies, hooks, json)
    369 self.prepare_headers(headers)
    370 self.prepare_cookies(cookies)
--> 371 self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
    372 self.prepare_auth(auth, url)
    374 # Note that prepare_auth must be last to enable authentication schemes
    375 # such as OAuth to work on a fully prepared request.
    376 
    377 # This MUST go after prepare_auth. Authenticators could add a hook

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py:511, in PreparedRequest.prepare_body(self, data, files, json)
    508 content_type = "application/json"
    510 try:
--> 511     body = complexjson.dumps(json, allow_nan=False)
    512 except ValueError as ve:
    513     raise InvalidJSONError(ve, request=self)

File /usr/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py:234, in dumps(obj, skipkeys, ensure_ascii, check_circular, allow_nan, cls, indent, separators, default, sort_keys, **kw)
    232 if cls is None:
    233     cls = JSONEncoder
--> 234 return cls(
    235     skipkeys=skipkeys, ensure_ascii=ensure_ascii,
    236     check_circular=check_circular, allow_nan=allow_nan, indent=indent,
    237     separators=separators, default=default, sort_keys=sort_keys,
    238     **kw).encode(obj)

File /usr/lib/python3.9/json/encoder.py:199, in JSONEncoder.encode(self, o)
    195         return encode_basestring(o)
    196 # This doesn't pass the iterator directly to ''.join() because the
    197 # exceptions aren't as detailed.  The list call should be roughly
    198 # equivalent to the PySequence_Fast that ''.join() would do.
--> 199 chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
    200 if not isinstance(chunks, (list, tuple)):
    201     chunks = list(chunks)

File /usr/lib/python3.9/json/encoder.py:257, in JSONEncoder.iterencode(self, o, _one_shot)
    252 else:
    253     _iterencode = _make_iterencode(
    254         markers, self.default, _encoder, self.indent, floatstr,
    255         self.key_separator, self.item_separator, self.sort_keys,
    256         self.skipkeys, _one_shot)
--> 257 return _iterencode(o, 0)

File /usr/lib/python3.9/json/encoder.py:179, in JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
    160 def default(self, o):
    161     """Implement this method in a subclass such that it returns
    162     a serializable object for ``o``, or calls the base implementation
    163     (to raise a ``TypeError``).
   (...)
    177 
    178     """
--> 179     raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
    180                     f'is not JSON serializable')

TypeError: Object of type JavaObject is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: @furas I've added the full error